# replace a vector to an upper Triangle matrix with different length

Tags: r, matrix, vector, replace

I want to have a triangle matrix by a vector when length of vector is less than replacement length. 
for example:

`v<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)`

and

`mat<- matrix(0,5,5)`.

If I use

`mat[upper.tri(mat, diag=FALSE)]<- v`

,the result is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    2    4    1
[2,]    0    0    3    5    2
[3,]    0    0    0    6    3
[4,]    0    0    0    0    4
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

But i don't want to replace more than length of vector in matrix. And i want to have:

```
[1,]    0    1    2    4    0
[2,]    0    0    3    5    0
[3,]    0    0    0    6    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adjust the `length` of `v` to that of the upper triangle. This yields some `NA` values that you can replace with zeroes.

```
u.tri <- upper.tri(mat, diag=FALSE)
mat[u.tri] <- `length<-`(v, length(u.tri)) 
mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    1    2    4    0
# [2,]    0    0    3    5    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    6    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```